# Getting Folder from folder RelativeID - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, storagefolder

How can I get folder from folder relative ID in Windows Phone 8.1?

`StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);`

this code works with full path, not relativeID.

Answer (score -1):

```
public sealed class StorageFolder
{
    IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder> GetFolderAsync(string name);
```

.
.
.

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderId);
```

Comment: I know it. But this is not work like this. GetFolderAsync method want you a path of folder not folder relative id.